# Working in localhost with absolute URLs and base tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

here's my silly question:
I'm working on my MAMP in a folder like

```
http://localhost/newsite/latest/
```

i setup all my img, css and js to be `src="/css/style.css"` with the slash in first position because i need to have absolute urls for canonical urls  like product/cat/item/ etc...

it works well on my online server of course but despite I set up a php condition to have this meta only on localhost

```
<base href="http://localhost/newsite/latest/">
```

the css files still remains broken...

solutions?

Comment: It might be because localhost isn't actually the start of the url, you may have to change something in a .config file somewhere, what do you think?

Comment: Have you tried removing the last forward slash in the `<base>` tag?

Comment: depends where project is in localhost and if you are using a port to access project. Don't need protocol and domain ..try just `/newsite/latest/` and check in dev tools network what is going wrong

Comment: what URL is the `Network` tab in devtools showing? check for any errors

Comment: basically /css/style.css it get requested as "localhost/css/style.css" instead of the desired "localhost/newsite/latest/css/style.css"

Comment: i always thought the initial slash was good but now i'm thinking i shoudl have used ./ ?